Why am I getting a TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str' when cutting up documents into chunks with Python and langchain?
Following is some code that I'm working on using Python and langchain to ingest a PDF document into a vector store for consumption as a reference manual for an AI initiative I'm working on.
Essentially the AI is going to be a reference tool to find answers within a specific set of documents, predominantly programming reference manuals.
So this is my code, written in Python, which works and converts the PDF into text which can be outputted via print to screen, yet when it goes to chunk it into pieces, I'm getting the following:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
The code is as follows:
# Description: This script is used to extract text from a PDF file and store it in a database.
import tika
from tika import parser
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma

# Parse the PDF
text = parser.from_file('..\mql5_new_compressed.pdf')["content"]

# Initialize the text splitter
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)

# print(text["content"])

# Split the text into chunks
chunks = text_splitter.create_documents([text["content"]])

I need to chunk this text as I'm going to bring it into a vector store to act as my database for searching.

I had declared the same variable name twice, "content", here:
# Parse the PDF
text = parser.from_file('..\mql5_new_compressed.pdf')["content"]

and then here:
chunks = text_splitter.create_documents([text["content"]])

All I needed to do was remove the first ["content"] from the text declaration and it worked.
